# URL encoding in python

Tags: python, string, http, url, ascii

Is there a simple method I'm missing in `urllib` or other library for this task?  URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.

Here's an example of an input and my expected output:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0; xx-xx; Galaxy Nexus Build/IFL10C) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30

Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Linux%3B+U%3B+Android+4.0%3B+xx-xx%3B+Galaxy+Nexus+Build%2FIFL10C%29+AppleWebKit%2F534.30+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F4.0+Mobile+Safari%2F534.30
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

For Python 2.x, use [`urllib.quote`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote)

> Replace special characters in string using the %xx escape. Letters, digits, and the characters '_.-' are never quoted. By default, this function is intended for quoting the path section of the URL. The optional safe parameter specifies additional characters that should not be quoted — its default value is '/'.

example:

```
In [1]: import urllib

In [2]: urllib.quote('%')
Out[2]: '%25'
```

**EDIT**:

In your case, in order to replace space by plus signs, you may use [`urllib.quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus)

example:

```
In [4]: urllib.quote_plus('a b')
Out[4]: 'a+b'
```

For Python 3.x, use [`quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote)

```
>>> import urllib
>>> a = "asdas#@das"
>>> urllib.parse.quote(a)
'asdas%23%40das'
```

and for string with space use [`quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus)

```
>>> import urllib
>>> a = "as da& s#@das"
>>> urllib.parse.quote_plus(a)
'as+da%26+s%23%40das'
```

Comment: or [urllib.quote_plus](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus), since OP wants `+` instead of `%20`.

Comment: but to get what the OP asks for, use `urllib.quote_plus`.

Comment: I believe, for Python 3.*, you should do `import urllib.parse ... urllib.parse.quote ...` or  `from urllib import parse ... parse.quote ...` rather than `import urllib ... urllib.parse.quote ...`, which will result in `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'parse'`, kind of similar to [imports in `werkzeug`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47688957/import-werkzeug-vs-from-werkzeug-import-security). Tested on Python 3.6.1.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that both [urllib.quote](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) and [urllib.quote_plus](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) throw an error if an input is a unicode string:

```
s = u'\u2013'
urllib.quote(s)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 1303, in quote
    return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
KeyError: u'\u2013'
```

As answered [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24954921/403431), one has to use 'UTF-8' explicitly:

```
urllib.quote(s.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you have a dict of several values, the best way to do it will be `urllib.urlencode`.