# How do you use google's API to do a simple search in Python?

Tags: python, xgoogle

I would love a nice, friendly example to help me out, or even a link to help me get started.

I'm baffled by google's "cloud application" interface and none of the search tutorials seem to readily point to vanilla google search. It seems they are overcomplicating and obfuscating.

I have a google dev account and I'm just trying to figure out what commands to put into python to get a search and return the URLs as a list like you can do in xgoogle, but more friendly to google and not liable to get banned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Web Search](https://developers.google.com/web-search/) API has **deprecated**, so [Google AJAX API](http://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest) is recommended.

You can custom your search like this:

```
import json
import urllib2

search_line = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=hello'
response = urllib2.urlopen(search_line)
search_results = json.loads(response.read())
print(search_results['responseData']['results'])
```

Comment: This answer is probably correct, but I think I need a wider answer to really understand how to make this work. I'm happy to read, but I don't know the correct starting point or what to google for. Should I be googling for json? for google ajax api?

Comment: To clarify, where would I go to learn how to format the search_line variable so that I know exactly what the rules are to be able to search for anything.

Right now I can't search for multi-word queries

Comment: update, figured out %20 is the way to add a space in a search. Is there a place to go to learn about all of the other "escape sequences"?

Comment: Watching [Google AJAX API](http://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest). Special characters should be encoded before sending to url, there is a reference [URL encoding in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8905864/url-encoding-in-python) @Pinwheeler

Comment: This API is no longer available, the alternative is [google-custom-search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/).