# Python encode url with special characters

Tags: python, urlencode

I want to encode URL with special characters. In my case it is: `š, ä, õ, æ, ø` (it is not a finite list).

`urllib2.quote(symbol)` gives very strange result, which is not correct. How else these symbols can be encoded?

Comment: What is the expected encode result?

Comment: "it is not a finite list" I might want to challenge this statement, seeing that the list of possible unicode characters is finite. ;-) Also, what @falsetru said. I get `urllib2.quote('ä') == '%C3%A4'`, which is correct.

Comment: urllib2.quote("Grønlandsleiret, Oslo, Norway") gives a %27Gr%B8nlandsleiret%2C%20Oslo%2C%20Norway%27 and I do a request to Google Maps (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%27Gr%B8nlandsleiret%2C%20Oslo%2C%20Norway%27) i get invalid request as a response.

Comment: @Bob, `urllib2.quote("Grønlandsleiret, Oslo, Norway")` returns `'Gr%C3%B8nlandsleiret%2C%20Oslo%2C%20Norway'` for me. And accessing corresponding url show me valid response: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Gr%C3%B8nlandsleiret%2C%20Oslo%2C%20Norway

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.8. May this be a problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> `urllib2.quote("Grønlandsleiret, Oslo, Norway")` gives a `%27Gr%B8nlandsleiret%2C%20Oslo%2C%20Norway%27`

Use UTF-8 explicitly then:

```
urllib2.quote(u"Grønlandsleiret, Oslo, Norway".encode('UTF-8'))
```

And always state the encoding in your file. See [PEP 0263](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

---

A non-UTF-8 string needs to be decode first, then encoded:

```
                           # You've got a str "s".
s = s.decode('latin-1')    # (or what the encoding might be …)
                           # Now "s" is a unicode object.
s = s.encode('utf-8')      # Encode as UTF-8 string.
                           # Now "s" is a str again.
s = urllib2.quote(s)       # URL encode.
                           # Now "s" is encoded the way you need it.
```

Comment: It works! encode('UTF-8') was that I was looking for.

Comment: Question: if i have an address as a variable, then urllib2.quote('u' + address.encode('UTF-8')) gives an error -> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128). What should I do?