# urlencoding python for Bing search

Tags: python, urlencode

I have the following URL `https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Awww.linkedin.com%20Employnet%2C+Inc.%20Monterey%20CA%20NOT%20jobs%20NOT%20pulse%20NOT%20profinder%%20NOT%20dir%20NOT%20company%20intitle%3AEmploynet%2C+Inc.`

when I go to the URL the search becomes like this `site:www.linkedin.com Employnet, Inc. Monterey CA NOT jobs NOT pulse NOT profinder% NOT dir NOT company intitle:Employnet, Inc.`

Here is my code:

```
url="https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Awww.linkedin.com%20Employnet%2C+Inc.%20Monterey%20CA%20NOT%20jobs%20NOT%20pulse%20NOT%20profinder%%20NOT%20dir%20NOT%20company%20intitle%3AEmploynet%2C+Inc."
url=url.replace("%3A",":").replace("%20"," ").replace("%2C+",", ")
search=re.search('.*?q=(.*)',url).groups()[0]
```

I Feel like this a poor method of doing it, is there a more technical way for proper encoding

Comment: Not an answer to your question. Why not [Bing Search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-web-search/web-sdk-python-quickstart)?

Comment: @Unni exactly what I am trying do but the search API required it to as in the "box"

Comment: Related, maybe dupe:  [URL encoding in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8905864/674039)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Python 3:

```
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> url="https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Awww.linkedin.com%20Employnet%2C+Inc.%20Monterey%20CA%20NOT%20jobs%20NOT%20pulse%20NOT%20profinder%%20NOT%20dir%20NOT%20company%20intitle%3AEmploynet%2C+Inc."
>>> urllib.parse.unquote_plus(url)
'https://www.bing.com/search?q=site:www.linkedin.com Employnet, Inc. Monterey CA NOT jobs NOT pulse NOT profinder% NOT dir NOT company intitle:Employnet, Inc.'
```

Or extract the query and [`unquote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote_plus) it:

```
>>> urllib.parse.unquote_plus(urllib.parse.urlsplit(url).query[2:])
'site:www.linkedin.com Employnet, Inc. Monterey CA NOT jobs NOT pulse NOT profinder% NOT dir NOT company intitle:Employnet, Inc.'
```

Comment: @madboy, it works on all URLs that have one one-letter key name in the query.